# How to use css to transform text

Tags: html, css

In my web app. I am using css "transform" property to rotate the text to 90degres on large and desktop screens. i want it to change automatically to 0degrees if the screen size is small. how can i implement it. please guide me.

HTML

```html
<div class="col-md-1 lift">
  <label>Legende</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.lift label {
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use media queries. You can learn about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).

To answer your question, this would apply rotation if screen width is larger than 500px:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .lift label {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using css media queries:

```css
// apply those css properites if the browser window is 700px wide or less
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .lift label {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

here is its [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), and now in 2022 you can just do it without using `transform`:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .lift label {
        rotate: -90deg;
    }
}
```

Plus soon with the new [Container Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries):

```css
@container (min-width: 500px) {
    .lift label {
        rotate: -90deg;
    }
}
```

As for [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) you can also use an utility class in HTML elements like in yours:

```html
<div class="col-md-1">
    <label class="-rotate-90">Legende</label>
</div>
```

Or in CSS:

```css
@apply -rotate-90;
```